# Google app engine handle html form post array

Tags: python, google-app-engine

My HTML code as following:

```
<INPUT type="text" name="txt[]">
<INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk[]"/>
```

I get the value in PHP by

```
<?php
$chkbox = $_POST['chk'];
$txtbox = $_POST['txt'];

foreach($txtbox as $a => $b)
  echo "$chkbox[$a]  -  $txtbox[$a] <br />";
?>
```

How do get the value in Google App Engine using Python?

Comment: OK, I think I shouldn't add the array in the html.

Comment: I've been searching for a related issue for a while, now, and suggest that this question be edited so that it is more readily searchable / found.  It took an IRC chat with an awesome individual in the #appengine room to link me to this question.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need that trick in Python. You can have for example many fields with the same names:

```
<INPUT type="text" name="txt">
<INPUT type="text" name="txt">
<INPUT type="text" name="txt">

<INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk">
<INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk">
<INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk">
```

Then get a list of all posted values for those names and merge them using `zip()`. Example for webapp (which uses webob as request wrapper):

```
txt = self.request.POST.getall('txt')
chk = self.request.POST.getall('chk')

for txt_value, chk_value in zip(txt, chk):
    print '%s - %s<br />' % (txt_value, chk_value)
```

Comment: Nice, here's the relevant docs: http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/request.html